# Finding minimum distance between $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | Ax = b\}$ and $U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|Cx=d\}$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Given $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | Ax = b\}$ and
>   $U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|Cx=d\}$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$,
>   $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ and
>   $d\in\mathbb{R}^p$, consider the problem of finding the point of $S$
>   which is closer to $U$. Make this an optimization problem and write
>   the conditions for optimality

I'm learning to solve $\min f(x)$ subject to $Ax = b$. In theory we'd simply transform this to an unconstrained problem by analyzing $\phi(\overline{x}+Z\gamma)$ where $\overline{x}$ is a solution for $Ax=b$, $Z$ is the matrix of the basis of $\ker(A)$ and $\gamma$ is our variable of unscontrained optimization. We must now find $\min \phi(\gamma)$ subject to the entire $\mathbb{R}^{\mbox{something}}$.

However for this problem I cannot identity which is going to be our function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, Maybe $\frac{1}{2}||x-y||^2$ for $x\in S$ and $y\in U$. And we're subject to $Ax=b$ and $Cx=d$. How should I proceed?

**UPDATE:**

Following the answer given below, our condition in one matrix would be

$$\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & C\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}$$

Basically, if $\overline{z}\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is a point such that $\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & C\end{bmatrix}\overline{z}=\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}$, any vector $d$ in $\ker \begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & C\end{bmatrix}$ is such that $\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & C\end{bmatrix}(\overline{z}+d) = \begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}$, so $\overline{z}+Z\gamma$ being $Z$ a basis of kernel of $\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & C\end{bmatrix}$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{m+p}$ is also a solution for any $\gamma$, because $Z\gamma\in\ker$ of that matrix.

Therefore we can construct the uncontstrained problem like this:

$$\phi(\gamma) = f(\overline{x}+Z\gamma) $$

which is equivalent to the constrained problem. So finding the minimum of the problem above is to find the minimum of the constrained problem. If $\gamma^*$ is a minimum of the unconstrained problem we have

$$\phi'(\gamma^*) = Z^t\nabla f(\overline{x}+Z\gamma) = 0$$

If the point is a minimum then the second order condition is

$$z^t\nabla^2 \phi(\gamma^*) z\ge 0$$

so

$$Z^t\nabla f(\overline{x}+Z\gamma)Z\ge 0$$

Are these conditions ok?

ps: my book says that the above condition ($Z^t\nabla f(\overline{x}+Z\gamma)Z\ge 0$) is the same as saying $y^t\nabla f(\overline{x}+Z\gamma)y\ge 0$ for all $y\in \ker Z$. Why?

Comment: For linear problems you can derive the Lagrange multiplier equations through elementary means. If $x\in S$ is as close as possible to $y$, then $y-x$ must be orthogonal to $S$. Thus it is in the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{Nul}A$, which is $\operatorname{Col}A^T$. Therefore $y-x=A^T\lambda$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R^m$. This is equivalent to the first equation in @LinAlg's's answer, and applying the same argument to $y\in U$ gives the second equation.

Comment: @Rahul but are the conditions I wrote ok?

Comment: @Paprika, the second order conditions are equivalent because $y = Z \alpha$. So, if the second order condition is $H \ge 0$, then this is equivalent to $\alpha^t H \alpha \ge 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right, since $y$ is different from $x$, you need $Cy=d$ instead of $Cx=d$:
$$\min_{x,y} \left\{ \frac{1}{2}||x-y||^2 : Ax=b, Cy=d \right\}$$
The Lagrangian is $L(x,y,\lambda,\mu) = 0.5(x-y)^T(x-y) + \lambda^T(Ax-b) + \mu^T(Cy-d)$. The stationarity conditions together with feasibility conditions form a linear system:
$$x-y + A^T \lambda = 0$$
$$x-y + C^T \mu = 0$$
$$Ax=b, Cy=d$$

Comment: Thank you so much by your answer. However, I do not have concepts of Lagrangian yet. Do you have a more elementary solution? Or at least an idea to guide me?

Comment: @Paprika Do you know how to solve least squares subject to linear constraints?

Comment: Subject to 1 constraint I think yes, but not more than one

Comment: @Paprika do you mean one system $Ax=b$?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean. I know how to minimize functions subject to 1 constraint. Could you write that? Thank you so much

Comment: @Paprika I would not know how to do this without Lagrangian, unless you know how to solve a least squares problem subject to a set of linear functions.

Comment: @Paprika With one constraint: $$\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & C\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}$$ You can also write $$x-y=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: can you take a look at my update? I wrote the conditions for optimality